# Summarize in a line

Tags: python, format

I want to add a leading zero if numbers (days) are less than 10.
Here is my tried to do it.
Is there any possible way to summarize this code in a single line? I have to write my script in a limited number of lines.

```
      e_day=int(row["DY"])
      e_dy='{:02}'.format(e_day)
```

Comment: `e_dy='{:02}'.format(int(row["DY"]))`